# Force delete of IBM Bluemix Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: ibm-cloud, kubernetes

I tried to set up a new Kubernetes cluster on IBM Bluemix and after a while I received the message that the deploy failed. To start over again I have tried to delete the cluster from the Bluemix interface, with no success. The error messages are not consistent, and go from elaborate messages error messages to the most common: `500: internal server error`.

The command line does not help either. I expected this to work

```
 bx cs cluster-rm k8s_demo
```

But the most of the time it leads to and EOF error. Somehow internal connections are an issue because

```
bx cs clusters
```

leads to the error

```
FAILED                                         
unable to connect to https://us-south.containers.bluemix.net/v1/clusters, please check your Internet Connection
```

most of the time. Every so often a list including the k8s_demo cluster appears, but being as persistent with the `cluster-rm` command has not brought such luck that the cluster is deleted.

Is there any other way I can try to start over again? Apart from setting up another Bluemix account of course, something I would prefer to avoid.

Comment: Contact the IBM Bluemix support.

Answer (score 0):

If this problem is continuing, I would suggest contacting IBM Support. They'll have the tools to troubleshoot what has happened with the cluster provisioning and/or deleting.

Comment: You can also try to curl that url: e.g. `curl https://us-south.containers.bluemix.net/v1/clusters`.  This should give back an error like `{"incidentID":"a7ac18be-19ae-4960-916e-9aaa1a7af84c","code":"E0001","description":"Your UAA and IAM tokens must be specified. If you are using the CLI, run bx login to log in to Bluemix. If you are using the API, include the Authorization and X-Auth-UAA-Token headers. Run bx iam oauth-tokens to retrieve your access tokens, and use the IAM token for the Authorization header, and the UAA token for the X-Auth-UAA-Token header.","type":"Authentication"}`

Comment: If curl does NOT give back that error, then there is likely a connection issue firewall, perhaps) between the system you're running on and the api server.